# ATMEGA328 USBasp schematic

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega, atmega328p, programmer

I have some problems about programming my ATMEGA328 with [USBasp programmer](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41zV2XQ8RQL._SX425_.jpg).

I have found different schematics for the connections and I do not know which I have to use (and I'm afraid to break something if I choose the wrong one):

**First one**:

[image]

The problem of this schematic is that I do not know which is the "verse" of the connector, and it is in contrast with the following other configurations.

**Second one**

[image]

The verse of the connector is specified, but this schematic is different from the previous one: Pin 3 is not more NC but is grounded.

**Third one**

[image]

The verse of the connector is specified, but this schematic is different from others: Pin 3 is  is grounded and 4 and 6 are not grounded.

My seller did not provide the datasheet for my programmer, so I have to consider the schematic of this generic USBasp programmer (it is identical to that of the previous picture).

Comment: I don't see a relevant difference. all have the pins you need on the same position.

Comment: what about Pin 3 that is NC in 1 and grounded in 2 and 3?

Comment: "not connected" or ground doesn't make a big difference if you don't use the pin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official USBasp](https://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) has no connection on pin 3, so whether it is grounded or left open circuit doesn't matter.

Pins 4 and 6 go to TXD and RXD in the programmer. TXD has a 270 Ω resistor in series so it is safe to 'short' it to ground, but better to leave it open circuit. RXD can be grounded or left open, as the serial port is not used in normal operation. Some USBASP clones ground both pins.

If you keep the programming cable and connections short then you should only need one ground wire, so just leave pins 3, 4 and 6 disconnected.